# Grand/sticky jQuery plugin only activate below 771px

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using Grand/sticky jQuery plugin to make my nav bar stick to top of page. https://github.com/garand/sticky. I was wondering if I could make this piece of code work only below 771px?

this is my what im using to make the nav stick:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){
   jQuery("nav").sticky({ topSpacing: -77});  
 });
```

and this is what I was thinking I could put the above code in to make it only work below 771px but It doesn't work when i put it in.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      function checkWidth() {
          var windowSize = jQuery(window).width();

          if (windowSize >= 771) {
              console.log(">");
          }
          else if (windowSize < 771) {
               console.log("<");
          }

      }

      // ON LOAD
      checkWidth();

      // RESIZE
      jQuery(window).resize(checkWidth);
  });
```

Am i on the right track? does the disable function have anything to do with it https://github.com/garand/sticky/pull/70/files?short_path=04c6e90

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle? I'm unsure of what you're trying to accomplish. Why do you only want it to work below 771px? Doesn't the plugin do that automatically?

Comment: Below? why are you checking `width`, instead of `scrollHeight`?

Comment: I have a different design wider than 771px that doesn't require the sticky nav but I cant seem to figure out how to disable it about that browser width. Ill try to put together a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

There was a forked version that included a .unstick, this was my soulution:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){
   jQuery("nav").sticky({ topSpacing: -77});  

   jQuery(window).resize(function(){
         if (jQuery(window).width() >= 771){  
            jQuery("nav").unstick();  
        }  
        if (jQuery(window).width() < 771){  
            jQuery("nav").sticky({ topSpacing: -77});    
        } 
   });


});
```